# Open3d Python Issue: No attribute 'estimate_normals'

Tags: python, numpy, mesh, trimesh, open3d

I am working with open3d for python3 on windows. It was installed through pip via `'pip install open3d-python'`. I've checked documentation and everything seems right with my script, which attempts to convert a point cloud file (.ply) to a mesh (.stl). However, on execution I get an `attribute error: 'open3d.open3d.geometry.PointCloud' has no attribute 'estimate_normals'`. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Here is my script

```
import open3d as o3d
import trimesh
import numpy as np

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("pointcloud.ply")
pcd.estimate_normals()
#pcd = pcd2.normals
# estimate radius for rolling ball
distances = pcd.compute_nearest_neighbor_distance()
avg_dist = np.mean(distances)
radius = 1.5 * avg_dist

mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting(pcd,o3d.utility.DoubleVector([radius, radius * 2]))

trimesh = trimesh.Trimesh(np.asarray(mesh.vertices), np.asarray(mesh.triangles),vertex_normals=np.asarray(mesh.vertex_normals))

trimesh.export('stuff.stl')
```

---

### EDIT

I read somewhere that compiling the original package from source would do the trick, but I'm a mac user, and am trying to do this on Windows, so I can't figure out how to do that. here is the github link for the package https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem and found that the issue happened because of the wrong version of open3d which was installed via `pip install open3d-python`. For me it was `v0.6.0`.
The documentation is based on the new releases. Starting with version `v0.8.0` open3d should be installed as `pip install open3d` or `conda install -c open3d-admin open3d` for conda. Found that information in [releases](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/releases). It solved the problem on my mac.

Comment: it is very helpful, you can use also pip install open3d==0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Uninstalling different version of open3d installed as `open3d` and `open3d-python`:
   `pip uninstall open3d open3d-python`
2. Installing `open3d 0.8`:
   `pip install open3d==0.8.0.0`
3. Calculate the surface normals:
   `pcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))`
4. Visualize surface normals by pressing `n` when the display window opens up to view the normals:
   `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])`